# LXDE (Lubuntu) Menu based on User

Tags: lubuntu, menu, lxde

I've been running Lubuntu for about 4 years now (since I think 12.04 actually?), however, something unforeseen happened.
I got a relationship that actually lasted for more than 2 years o.0

Anyways, back on topic, she has to do homework now and then on my laptop, which is perfectly fine by me.
I created a new user for her so she doesn't have to see my `documents`. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
However, I have a tonne of things in my menu that she doesn't have to bother with like:

- `Oracle Java` stuff (she does need the `JRE`, but she can still access that)
- `Etherape`
- the `Wine` folder
- a lot of stuff out of the `Preferences` folder
- the `System Tools` folder

Just to name a few.
However, I can't simply throw them out for everybody, because I do need them.
Does anybody here know a good (and preferably simple - and safe?) solution for it?
It's not that I don't trust her, it's just that I want to strip as much stuff she doesn't need as possible.

Cheers!

Comment: I guess you could check the .desktop files under `/usr/share/applications` and move the ones you want only for you to see to your local folder `~/.local/share/applications`. I don't know if applications would recreate this files (on update, for example), so that's why I consider it a guess and don't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to hide things in the menu it's quite easy. While logged in as the user whose menu you wish to modify, just open the file manager (pcmanfm) and click on Applications in the left column.

You will see a list of icons corresponding to the menu categories. If you double-click a category, you will see icons corresponding to the applications listed under that category. Simply right-click the application you wish to remove from the menu and select Hide from the context menu. You can do the same thing to the top level icons and hide the whole category.

If you do not see Applications listed in the left column of the file manager, select Edit/Preferences/Layout in the file manager menu, and tick the box next to Applications under the heading Show in Places.

You may have to have the user log out and back in to see the changes.

Comment: I found the menu, select `Etherape`, right click, select `hide` and...  
`Failed to create file '/home/daphne/.local/share/applications/etherape.desktop.IQJUXY': No such file or directory`

Comment: Weird. It sounds like Daphne's user account was not set up properly.  Does `/home/daphne/.local/share/applications` exist?

Comment: No it didn't. after a long trial & error, it finnally worked :D yay :D